# Android smoothScrollTo not invoking onScrollStateChanged

Tags: android, listview, scroll, event-driven

I am using `smoothScrollBy()` to scroll to a specific position in a `ListView`. I would like to be notified when the `ListView` is done scrolling to integrate it with the current `onScrollStateChanged()` event that is fired off when the user scrolls with their finger.

Currently I'm using a `Timer` that runs 100ms after the duration of the smooth scroll, but that is not as event driven as I would prefer.

Comment: I can confirm from my own debugging that the `smoothScroll*` functions won't trigger the scrolling state changes, and therefore render the `OnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged()` callbacks useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have implemented the OnScrollListener for your listview you can watch for when the ScrollState changes. Use a global boolean (isScrolling) set to true when you call smoothScrollBy() and then set it to false once the OnScrollListener registers a ScrollState of SCROLL_STATE_IDLE.

```
sidebar1.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(currentPosition, 0, 500);
isScrolling = true;

sidebar1.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        isScrolling = false;
    }

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

}
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` came in at API 11.

Comment: True, but aren't you just looking to be notified when the scrolling is done?  You should be able to use smoothScrollBy and implement the listener in conjunction with a while loop that continuously polls the isScrolling state.

Comment: From my experience, `smoothScrollBy()` does not invoke `onScrollStateChanged()`, and as of this time I am using a `Timer` to poll once the scrolling should be done.

Comment: Another thought would be to poll and check the    getLastVisiblePosition()    once that changes and then stays consistent you can probably be certain scrolling has ceased.  It's not really event driven but should get the job done pretty well.

Comment: On a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1) smoothScrollBy *does* trigger a call to onScrollStateChanged.  Most likely, this also happens on a Huawei Media PadS7 - 301u (Android 3.2).  On 2.x release, afaik, the smoothScrollBy *does not* trigger onScrollStateChanged